# Correctness of a regular expression

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, .net-2.0

I'm trying to create a regex which will match either one of the following -

```
FVAL(A)
FVAL("A")
FVAL(A,B)
FVAL("A",B)
FVAL("A","B")
FVAL(A,"B")
FVAL(A,B,C)
FVAL("A",B,C)
FVAL("A","B",C)
FVAL("A","B","C")
FVAL("A",B,"C")
FVAL(A,"B","C")
```

Regex -

`FVAL\s*\(\s*["*]\s*\w+\s*["*]\s*,*\s*["*]\s*\w+\s*["*]\s*,*\s*,*\s*["*]\s*\w+\s*["*]\s*\)`

This regex is supposed to return all and any form of the function that is used.

For e.g. - 
 
If match string were - `FVAL(A,"B")+5` then match group should be `FVAL(A,"B")`

P.S. - I'm ignoring white spaces in match string, but they can be there.

Comment: your sixth example, `FVAL("A,"B")`, is that correct? (the `"A`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expression is *way* too complicated.

```
FVAL\("?\w+"?(?:,"?\w+"?){0,2}\)
```

Breakdown:

```
FVAL         # "FVAL"
\(           # "("
"?           # an optional double quote
\w+          # at least one word character
"?           # an optional double quote
(?:          # group
  ,          #   a comma
  "?\w+"?    #   quote - word character - quote
){0,2}       # end group, repeat 0-2 times
\)           # ")"
```

Insert whitespace `\s` into the expression where you see fit.

Comment: Brilliant. Solved it. Regex is so powerful.

Comment: @Soham If you want to make sure that quotes are consistent, you can use this `("?)\w+\1` in place of `"?\w+"?` (where `\1` must be the respective group number). This way the regex expects a closing quote if (and only if) there also was an opening quote.

Comment: I'm using this `FVAL\s*\(\s*""?\s*\w+\s*""?\s*(?:\s*,\s*""?\s*\w+\s*""?\s*){0,2}\)`. Because of space used I cannot use `\1`. Is there any other way?

Comment: What does the `\s*` have to do with the `\1`?

Comment: Its giving me an error that group `\1` is not defined if I use `FVAL\s*\(\s*""?\s*\w+\s*""?\s*(?:\s*,\s*""?\s*\w+\s*\1\s*){0,2}\)`

Comment: @Soham That's because you did not define group 1. Read my comment again, there's something in there that you did not do in your expression.